# Are there any security implications for having the Temporary Directory inside the Drupal root folder?

Tags: installation, security

I'm having trouble finding the tmp dir of a particular host and I'm wondering if there is any reason not to just stick it inside the Drupal root.

Comment: Not sure, but [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) will get you the path to the system tmp folder

Comment: Thank you! Been writing php for 5 years and still discovering functions like this all the time.